# Google Plus Sign In, OpenID connect and seamless authetnication

Tags: google-plus, google-apps-marketplace

We currently use OpenID authentication for the applications we develop. This is going to be deprecated in April 2015, and we have to migrate to OpenID Connect/Google Plus Sign-In before.

However, right now we take advantage of the seamless authentication provided by OpenID and Google Apps Console. That is to say, if we create an app which uses OpenID for authentication, and then we install this app through the Marketplace or Google Apps Console, the user is not prompted for a confirmation or warning screen during the OpenID authentication.

This is because, during the Marketplace/Google Apps Console app installation, the admins have indicated that they trusted the OpenID realm of this application.

Will this behavior still be effective with G+ SignIn and OpenID connect ? Is there anything specific to do to enforce this behavior ?

Comment: domain-wide delegation with oauth 2.0 -http://stackoverflow.com/a/22134464/37759

Comment: Hi dev.e.loper, thank you but domain-wide delegation is not an authentication protocol.

Comment: Correct. Domain-wide delegation is a process describing admin's consent to for all users. Seamless SSO with OAuth 2.0 is described here - http://googleappsdeveloper.blogspot.com/2012/11/domain-wide-delegation-of-authority-and.html Hoping this will help. Not sure about G+ sign-in and OpenId connect. Aren't they deprecating OpenId connect and moving with Oauth 2.0?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've finally found the solution and wrote [a blog post about the whole process](http://david-codes.blogspot.com/2014/07/how-to-provide-seamless-single-sign-on.html).

Answer (score 3):

The behavior will not change. We've got docs coming soon on this, and I'll update this answer once they are published. But the main point is that you will be able to authenticate your users without prompting a consent dialog.

We do mention this in the [Intro to the New Google Apps Marketplace](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XxX4oNi_Uyc) video, so feel free to take a look.

Comment: I am trying to use Google + sign in button in a marketplace application but I can't get it to be seamless for the user after the domain's admin installs it and gives permition. Is there any documentation available to have a guide to get this google marketplace requirement?

Comment: Hey Joanna, I cannot find any doc related to seamless authentication. Can you help me ?