# Google + Sign in button autorization screen

Tags: google-apps-marketplace

I have an application that I want to upload to the Google Marketplace. The application takes the email of the user using the Google + sign in button. The problem is that after the administrator of the domain installs the application, the user still sees the authorization screen (the one that says: this app would like to: 1.- know who you are 2.- view your email address) and the marketplace people have told us that this is not correct, the user only has to click in the button and not to be asked for permission.

This is the code that I'm using:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    (function() {
        var po = document.createElement('script');
        po.type = 'text/javascript';
        po.async = true;
        po.src = 'https://apis.google.com/js/client:plusone.js';
        var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
        s.parentNode.insertBefore(po, s);
    })();

    function signinCallback(authResult) {
        if (authResult['status']['signed_in']) {
            console.log(authResult);
            gapi.client.load('oauth2', 'v2', function() {
                gapi.client.oauth2.userinfo.get().execute(function(resp) {
                    console.log(resp.email);
                    document.getElementById('email').value = resp.email;
                    document.getElementsByClassName('popupEspera')[0].style.display='block';
                    envia();
                })
            });

            document.getElementById('signinButton').setAttribute('style',
                    'display: none');
        } else {

            console.log('Sign-in state: ' + authResult['error']);
        }
    }
</script>
<table width="95%">     
    <tr>
        <td align="right"><span id="signinButton"> <span
                class="g-signin" data-callback="signinCallback"
                data-clientid="CLIENT_ID"
                data-cookiepolicy="single_host_origin"
                data-scope="https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email">
            </span>
        </span></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Could you tell me how can I make it for not showing the authorization screen to the user once the administrator has installed the application in the domain?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I'm working on similar problem. When an administrator for a domain installs your app, they see initial authorization screen and accept.  Administrator's consent should grant you the right to access whatever scope you specified. So users that had that app installed by administrator should not see the authorization prompt because their administrator already consented.

The process is called **domain-wide delegation**. It has recently changed. See my question & answer here https://stackoverflow.com/a/22134464/37759

**update** Google App users can sign into your app via [Google universal navigation bar](https://support.google.com/a/answer/172981?hl=en) or directly from your website. When user is signing in directly from your website you'll need to provide them with [Sign-in With Google Apps button](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/marketplace/integrate#authentication).

Comment: I'm using this to get authorization for different scopes, but I need a way to know the email of the user that is using the application. I'm working with Google App Engine so I tried the UserService, but Google have told me that we can not use it. So I've used this Google + sign in button to get the email and be able to use domain-wide delegation. And if I use domain-wilde delegation with "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email" scope, the application gets as email the Service account email, not the user's one. Is there any other way to get the email?

Comment: Maybe use Directory API to retrieve user information? https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/guides/manage-users#get_user

Comment: The directory API retrieves all the users list, but is not able to know which one of the users is using the application at the moment; so that's not a valid solution

Comment: That is interesting. If user is signed in, shouldn't you have their google id available somewhere?

Comment: No, because when the user enters in the application is not signed in on Google; the Google + sign in button is the one that provides the sign in and the one that is giving me problems to publicate the app on the marketplace

Comment: I think you are describing a situation where a Google App user is signing in directly from your site instead of going through universal navigation bar. I'll update my answer with more detail.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/48977/discussion-between-user1930068-and-dev-e-loper)

Comment: Does someone know how to do it?