# Google Plus Login (Server Side Flow) and Google Apps Marketplace

Tags: google-plus, google-apps-marketplace

I'm trying to use Google Plus Login (Server side Flow) and trying to figure out what I need to do in order to achieve [seamless SSO sign up](https://developers.google.com/apps-marketplace/practices#5_use_one-click_single_sign-on) for Google Apps Marketplace.

The G+ [server side flow](https://developers.google.com/+/web/signin/server-side-flow) requires that I ask for offline access. I think that's way I'm still seen the consent screen. Is there a way to go with G+ server side flow and be compliant with Google Apps Marketplace requirements?

Answer (score 0):

I am afraid Google Apps Marketplace doesn't support offline access yet. See response to [Google Apps Marketplace SDK + Domain-wide OAuth 2 SSO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20668643/google-apps-marketplace-sdk-domain-wide-oauth-2-sso)