# How do I prevent the user from being asked to grant permissions for a Google Apps Marketplace app that the domain administrator has approved

Tags: single-sign-on, google-oauth, google-apps-marketplace

I've been trying to convert an old style Marketplace app to the new way of doing things, but I keep having the user prompted for authorization when they first follow the Universal Navigation link (the app was installed onto the domain via the 'Test Install Flow' link on the marketplace SDK).

When I request the 'openid email' scopes, the prompt appears, but if I specify a separate scope (instead of, not in addition to 'openid email') that is part of the app, it doesn't prompt the user for auth (unless I request offline access, which I want for parity of features with the previous version, but one problem at a time...).

Sample code using the [google api nodejs client](https://github.com/google/google-api-nodejs-client/):

```js
var http = require('http');
var googleapis = require('googleapis');
var url_parse = require('url');

var OAuth = googleapis.auth.OAuth2;

var client = new OAuth(
    CLIENT_ID
    CLIENT_SECRET
    REDIRECT_URL
);

http.createServer(dispatcher).listen(80);

function dispatcher(req, res){
    res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/html'});
    var url = url_parse.parse(req.url, true);
    if(url.pathname === '/auth') {
        auth_time(res);
    } else if (url.pathname === '/callback') {
        console.log('looking good');
        client.getToken(url.query.code, function(err, tokens){
            console.log(tokens);
            client.setCredentials(tokens);
            res.end(render_page('yep'));
        });
    } else {
        res.end(render_page('different page'));
        console.log(req.url);
    }
}

function auth_time(res){
    res.end(render_page('<a href="'+client.generateAuthUrl({
        scope: 'openid email https://www.google.com/m8/feeds', //Prompts
        // scope: 'https://www.google.com/m8/feeds', //Doesn't prompt
        include_granted_scopes: 'true',
        access_type: 'online'
    })+'">Click for auth</a>'));
}

function render_page(contents){
    return '<html><head><title>The page</title></head><body>'+contents+'</body></html>';
}
```

This [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23512142/apps-marketplace-sso) has an answer suggesting that `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.me` is added to the list of scopes used on the Marketplace SDK, but that scope is removed on page refresh (I'm guessing it is treated as identical to one or both of `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email` & `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile` which are automatically set as scopes and are not removable.

Comment: When you tried adding the plus.me scope to the list, did you remember to click the 'Save Changes' button at the bottom of the page?  Doing so should allow the scope addition to persist.

Comment: I've heard elsewhere that you need to request both the "profile" and "email" scope. Can you try that?